# Install different version of merge module depending on processor architecture

Tags: visual-studio, installation, merge-module, vdproj

I have a Windows .net solution that is deployed with a Visual Studio Deployment project.
My exe is a win32 app that runs fine on either a x86 or x64 windows.

However I included a merge module (*.msm) from a third party vendor which is available in a x86 and x64 version.

Now I could copy my whole deploy project and just change the msm, but I'm a lazy guy and the best thing would be to include both msm's in my installer and only install the module which fits the processor of the client machine.

Is there a way to do this with Visual Deployment projects?
Merge Modules seem to lack a Condition property like included exe / dll files have.